# When adding document to index and sepcial characters like *, #, @ error

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

The request is invalid. Details: actions : 0: Invalid document key: 'TESTS123*14'. Keys can only contain letters, digits, underscore (_), dash (-), or equal sign (=). If the keys in your source data contain other characters, we recommend encoding them with a URL-safe version of Base64 before uploading them to your index. If that is not an option, you can add the 'allowUnsafeKeys' query string parameter to disable this check.

We use .Net Sdk, how to set the allowUnsafeKeys?

Tried to URL-safe version of Base64 but it stores only encoded content, not the actual content.

Comment: Can you please provide the SDK package and version you are using to search documents (example: Azure.Search.Documents version=11.4.0)?

Comment: we are using Azure.Search.Documents version=11.4.0

Comment: Any updates on this issue? Please let me know if you need more information from me.

Comment: Since this looks like an SDK possible issue those are logged through GitHub directly in SDK  library issues. This may take more time via a different channel. We are doing the best we can to get a response.

Comment: SDK team has confirmed the error is coming from the service but since not documented, I am checking for the reason and way to use it to update the documentation. and if not to correct the error accordingly.

Comment: We are confirming the syntax in SDK. Documentation will be updated in the coming weeks (API and SDK) to reflect this. When querying and indexing in the API you would do: GET indexes/foo/docs/1234?allowUnsafeKeys and when inserting the doc POST /indexes/foo/docs/index?allowUnsafeKeys

Comment: Can you please try:  SearchOptons options = new SearchOptions()
    {
        allowUnsafeKeys = true
    };

Comment: Error occurs while indexing the documents. searchClient.IndexDocuments(). This call takes IndexDocumentsOptions but I don't see any option to set allowUnsafeKeys

Comment: Also, I have looked at the source of Searchption I didn't see any allowUnsafeKeys option. Do I have to use any specific version of SDK to see this option?

Comment: I'll follow up with SDK team accordingly. Like I mentioned earlier, usually SDK issues are better addressed by opening directly an issue in Github (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Azure.Search.Documents_11.4.0/sdk/search/Azure.Search.Documents/src). It may take some time to follow up through Stackoverflow. When I have a response I'll let you know.

Comment: SDK team has apologized about the details provided before and confirmed that this option is not available yet in any SDK version since it was missing from REST API documentation as well. They have added a work item to support this. No ETA right now. In the meantime a workaround is using a custom HttpPipelinePolicy where it sets this query parameter, though handling whether the query parameter should be included on a request-by-request basis will be harder. REST API call would be GET indexes/foo/docs/1234?allowUnsafeKeys and when inserting the doc POST /indexes/foo/docs/index?allowUnsafeKeys

Comment: Gia, Thank you so much for your update. Are you saying, even though we are using the .Net SDK  still we can use the HttpPipeinePolicy to add these extra URL parameters? .Please provide some usage sample.

Comment: I was able to use the HttpPipelinePolicy and index the keys with special characters. When I try to search the key in the search portal with allowUnsafeKey like this search=SomeKeywith*14&allowUnsafeKeys search is not returning the record.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry about not getting back earlier. If you have specific use cases, can you please log a support request? Support team will need your index JSON definition and a few docs you are indexing since this behavior may be related to Analyzers used. We request this info not to be exposed over the internet. Thank you.

Comment: Please let me know, where I can get in touch with the support team.

Comment: Sure here it is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request

Answer (score 1):

If anyone interested in custom policy with sdk:

1. **Register your index client with DI**

```cs
 builder.AddSearchIndexClient(configuration.GetSection("IndexClient"))
            .WithName("IndexName").ConfigureOptions(client =>
            {
                client.AddPolicy(new AllowUnsafeKeyPolicy(), HttpPipelinePosition.PerCall);
            });
```

2. **Create AllowUnsafeKeyPolicy class like below**

```cs
    public class AllowUnsafeKeyPolicy : HttpPipelinePolicy
    {
        public override void Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory<HttpPipelinePolicy> pipeline)
        {
            message.Request?.Uri.AppendQuery("allowUnsafeKeys", "true");
            ProcessNext(message, pipeline);
        }

        public override async ValueTask ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory<HttpPipelinePolicy> pipeline)
        {
            await ProcessNextAsync(message, pipeline);
        }
    }
```